# compute integral of function of distance to the boundary only

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

How does one compute the integral

$
\int_{\Omega_{\epsilon}} f( d(x))\  dx = ?
$

where $d(x)$ is the distance to the boundary and $\Omega_\epsilon := \{ x\in \Omega:  d(x)<\epsilon\}$, supposing that the boundary is smooth and $\epsilon$ is taken sufficiently small to ensure that there exists a point $p(x)\in \partial \Omega$ such that $d(x) = |x-p(x)|$ and $\nabla d(x) = -\hat{n}(p(x))$ for all $x\in \Omega_\epsilon$.

I imagine such an integral can be computed using some form of generalized polar coordinates tailored to the boundary, but I don't immediately see how.   Can anyone provide a reference where this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [tubular neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood), which has a nice description for small $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Adding to this, in a tubular neighborhood $d(x)$ will be realized as the length of a small geodesic normal to the boundary.

Comment: Indeed, although differential topologists don't usually think this way, you can obtain the one-sided tubular neighborhood of the boundary (and, more generally, for closed submanifolds) by exponentiating the normal bundle, i.e., by following geodesics normal to the boundary (submanifold).